# Topologies of equivalent metrics

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On $X=  {\bf R}^2 - \{ (x_1,0)|\ x_1>0 \}$ define two metrics :

$d(x,y) = |x-y|$ and $d_2$ is a path metric.

Then $$ d(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y),\ d_2(x,y)\leq C(x,y)d(x,y) $$

Here if $x_n=(n,1/n),\ y_n = (n,-1/n),\ n>0$ then $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} C(x_n,y_n) = \infty \ (\ast)$$

So two metrics are not equivalent (Recall that equivalent norms define same topologies on normed spaces) But they define same topologies.

Even though it is not (uniform) equivalent, condition $\ast$ give same topologies ?

**Question** On a metric space $X$, if we have two metrics s.t. $$ f(x,y)d_2(x,y)\leq d(x,y) \leq g(x,y)d_2(x,y)$$ where $ f,\ g: X\times X \rightarrow {\bf R}$ are continuous functions, then do they give same topologies ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they determine the same topology. The point is that every point of $X$ admits a neighborhood (in the Euclidean topology) where the two metrics agree. Why do you find it so strange?  Incidentally, $X$ is not a normed vector space.